# pulling images from multiple urls

Tags: python, image, opencv, url, urlrequest

I want to download images from differenturls (in the csv file) every second.

I can download the images. However, my code over writes the images after every second. How do I write them with different names each time so that it does not overwrite the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned you're downloading images every three seconds. I would suggest you add the current time in seconds format before your image name.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
filename = now . filename
```

I'm just giving you the idea. You can implement your code in your own style.

*I might have a syntax error here as I'm not a python-dev. But, I hope you get the idea.*